# Meteor Create PDF on Server via base64 String Then Email Attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Clientside (using the [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) package):

```js
'click #testClick' (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var element = document.getElementById('testReport');
  var opt = {
    jsPDF: {
      orientation: 'landscape'
    }
  }
  html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).outputPdf().then((result) => {
    Meteor.call('testPDF', result, function(error, res) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      } else {
        console.log("email sent");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Server Method:

```js
testPDF: function(data) {
  fs = Npm.require('fs');
  base64String = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
  let dir = process.cwd();
  let fileName = 'file.pdf'
  fs.writeFile(dir + fileName, base64String, 'base64', function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Err ', err);
    }
  });

  //Want this to work, but attachment is not working
  // Email.send({
  //   to: "test@test.com",
  //   from: "noreply@something.com",
  //   subject: "PDF",
  //   html: '<body><h1>Hello</h1></body>',
  //   attachments: [
  //       {
  //         filename: fileName
  //       }
  //     ]
  // });
}
```

It actually does create the PDF file, but I can't open it. I get a corrupt error. If I use the .save() method in the html2pdf package THAT works and I can download the .pdf in the browser. Basically, I am just trying to create a .PDF from an HTML element and email it...

Comment: seen this issue before, I started using jsreport to do this with meteor, just a thought, not promoting anything here.

Comment: Seems pretty interesting, but not quite what I am looking to do :( I am thinking I am pretty close with my solution, but wondering if perhaps there is something up with the string that is being produced by html2pdf